# Am I right to say that this map can't be extended by continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $f \colon \mathcal{C}[-T,0]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(x)=f_0(x(0))$$
where $f_0 \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz.

Then as $\mathcal{C}[-T,0]$ is dense in $L^2[-T,0]$ is it possible to extend uniquely $f$ by $\tilde f \colon L^2[-T,0] \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$\tilde f (x)= \lim_n f(x_n)=\lim_n f_0(x_n(0))$$
where $x_n \in \mathcal{C}[-T,0]$ with $x_n \to x$ with convergence in the $L^2$-norm ?

To me it seems not: we cannot guarantee that $x_n(0) \to x(0)$ converges when $x_n \to x$ in $L^2$

Am I right?

Comment: $f$ and $\bar f$ have the same domain, so it is not correct to say that one "extends" the other.

Comment: well no $f$ is defined on $\mathcal C$ while $\tilde f$ on $L^2$

Comment: You are right: $L^2$-convergence does not imply pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a sequence of continuous functions $x_n$ such that $x_n=0$ in $[-T,-1/n]$, $x_n=1$ in $[-1/(2n),0]$ and $x_n$ affine in $[-1/n,-1/(2n)]$. Then $x_n$ goes to $0$ in $L^2$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but $x_n(0)=1$.